# Neo4J - Cypher: shortest path between multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say we have 4 nodes:

`{id:1, name:"one"}
{id:2, name:"two"}
{id:3, name:"three"}
{id:4, name:"four"}`

Suppose node 1 is linked to node 2, node 2 to 3, 3 to 4 so the result would be something like:

`(1)-->(2)-->(3)-->(4)`

How would I be able to get the shortest path between multiple given nodes in any given order? A few examples:

`findShortestPath(2,4,3)` should result in: `(2)-->(3)-->(4)`

`findShortestPath(3,1)` should result in: `(1)-->(2)-->(3)`

`findShortestPath(4,1)` should result in: `(1)-->(2)-->(3)-->(4)`

`findShortestPath(3,2)` should result in: `(2)-->(3)`

I have tried something like this, but I feel like I'm going the wrong way and it's not the most performant solution. Note that my query gets constructed programmatically since it can contain any number and kind of nodes.

If the input would be: (2),(3),(1)

That would result in a double for loop constructing something like this:

`match p=allShortestPaths((p2)-[*]-(p3)),allShortestPaths((p2)-[*]-(p1)),allShortestPaths((p3)-[*]-(p1)) where p1.name="Keanu Reeves" and p2.name="Gene Hackman" and p3.name="Clint Eastwood" return p;`

My problem is that I can't provide multiple nodes to the `allShortestPaths()` function. Only 2 nodes with 1 relation is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through all the pairs of nodes, and check that the other nodes are in the possible paths between these pairs:

```
WITH ["Keanu Reeves", "Gene Hackman", "Clint Eastwood"] AS names
UNWIND names AS nn
  MATCH (n {name: nn})
  WITH collect(n) AS nds

UNWIND nds AS n1
  UNWIND nds AS n2
  WITH nds, n1, n2 WHERE id(n1) > id(n2)
    MATCH path = allShortestPaths((n1)-[*]-(n2))
    WITH nds, path WHERE ALL(n IN nds WHERE n IN nodes(path))
RETURN path ORDER BY length(path) ASC
```

Comment: Oh right, this seems interesting. I had stumbled upon the double unwind on the Neo4J website. However, the part WHERE ALL (bla IN bla) seems what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: In the end, I was able to solve it thanks to your solution. I had to change it up a bit because instead of the name property, I used the ID of the node.

Comment: I have a problem that my nodes can be of a different kind. If I use this as a first line `WITH ["Keanu Reeves", "The Matrix", "Clint Eastwood"] AS names`, then I receive 3 nodes as a result, but The Matrix node is not in the graph even though Keanu Reeves has a relation to it (ACTED_IN). I would expect a node from The Matrix to Keanu Reeves and from Keanu to Clint Eastwood. Can you explain why this doesn't show up? Insated I get the same result as I would use Hackman.

Comment: The problem is that a movie type node does not have a `name` property, but there is a `title` property. So you need this change: `...   MATCH (n) WHERE n.name = nn OR n.title = nn ...`

Comment: Or like this: `...   MATCH (n) WHERE ANY(k IN keys(n) WHERE n[k] = nn) ...`

Comment: Well, in this case you are 100% right? However, in my live case, I use the id, and both labels have the id field obviously. I use `WHERE ID(n)` to solve that. But still I don't have the desired output. I have posted a new question to avoid having 100 comments here :).