# Neo4J - Cypher: allShortestPaths through multiple nodes of multiple labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

Through my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444694/neo4j-cypher-shortest-path-between-multiple-nodes/51445723#51445723) and the information [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/all-shortest-paths-between-set-of-nodes/), I was able to create a query for my situation. However, when I tested my solution, it seemed that nodes of multiple labels would not return the desired output.

Let's say, Keany Reeves acted in The Matrix and Keanu Reeves knows Clint Eastwood and Clint Eastwood knows Hugh Jackman. In that case, if I were to use this query:

```
WITH ["Keanu Reeves", "Matrix", "Hugh Jackman"] AS names
UNWIND names AS nn
  MATCH (n {name: nn})
  WITH collect(n) AS nds

UNWIND nds AS n1
  UNWIND nds AS n2
  WITH nds, n1, n2 WHERE id(n1) > id(n2)
    MATCH path = allShortestPaths((n1)-[*]-(n2))
    WITH nds, path WHERE ALL(n IN nds WHERE n IN nodes(path))
RETURN path ORDER BY length(path) ASC;
```

The desired output would be a node of Keanu Reeves pointing to a node of The Matrix. Then Also pointing to Keanu Reeves would be Clint Eastwood's node. Clint's node would be pointing to Hugh Jackman's node. Something like this:

`(HJ)-KNOWS->(CE)-KNOWS->(KR)-ACTED_IN->(TM)`

However, my current output does not contain my 3 starting nodes. I think I don't understand the double unwind completely. Is it like a double for loop where you compare to the next item sorted by id?

Btw, in my real life situation, I use id's instead of names, but that doesn't matter for this case. I solve that with a `WHERE ID(bla)` clause.

Comment: In your DB, perhaps the name "Matrix" is actually stored as "The Matrix"?

Comment: If you're using the built-in movies graph, also note that :Movie nodes have a `title` property, not a `name` property, so it's likely that your "Matrix" entry didn't match to a node by this or cybersam's observation.

Comment: I am aware of the "name" and "title" properties. In my live case, I use the ID(n) function. All type of entities always have that I think.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire Show an example of real data and a real query.